# Tomcat 7 redirect URL - Proxy

Tags: tomcat

I'm trying to create a redirect rule in Tomcat like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/value to www.otherdomain.com/value
```

I don't use httpd so redrict rule is not an option.

I can't find any way to do this without using a 3rd party like [Tuckey](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

is there any option to add a connector or any configuration to the server.xml in Tomcat (or any other conf file)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tuckey's url-rewrite filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) is in fact a good option, but it does require that you add a dependency on a third-party library.

You didn't mention your Tomcat version, but Tomcat 8.0 and later have the [RewriteValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html) which is similar.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question. I'm using Tomcat 7 so RewriteValve isn't an option

Comment: I'm not absolutely positive, but you might be able to use the RewriteValve from Tomcat 8 in Tomcat 7. You'd just have to extract the Valve class(es) from Tomcat 8's libraries. YMMV.